# Kube-proxy with IPVS mode doesn't keep a connection

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy, ipvs

I have a k8s cluster with an `ipvs` kube-proxy mode and a database cluster outside of k8s.

In order to get access to the DB cluster I created service and endpoints resources:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: database
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 192.168.255.9
  - ip: 192.168.189.76
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    protocol: TCP
```

Then I run a pod with MySQL client and try to connect to this service:

```
mysql -u root -p password -h database
```

In the network dump I see a successful TCP handshake and successful MySQL connection. On the node where the pod is running (hereinafter the worker node) I see the next established connection:

```
sudo netstat-nat -n | grep 3306
tcp   10.0.198.178:52642             192.168.189.76:3306            ESTABLISHED
```

Then I send some test queries from the pod in an opened MySQL session. They all are sent to the same node. It's expected behavior.

Then I monitor established connections on the worker node. After about 5 minutes the established connection to the database node is missed.

But in the network dump I see that TCP finalization packets are not sent from the worker node to the database node. As a result, I get a leaked connection on the database node.

How `ipvs` decides to drop an established connection? If `ipvs` drops a connection, why it doesn't finalize TCP connection properly? Is it a bug or do I misunderstand something with an `ipvs` mode in kube-proxy?

Comment: Are there any relevant logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kube-proxy and Kubernetes don't help to balance persistent connections.

The whole concept of the long-lived connections in Kubernetes is well described in [this article](https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-long-lived-connections):

> Kubernetes doesn't load balance long-lived connections, and some Pods
> might receive more requests than others. If you're using HTTP/2, gRPC,
> RSockets, AMQP or any other long-lived connection such as a database
> connection, you might want to consider client-side load balancing.

I recommend going through the whole thing but overall it can be summed up with:

> - Kubernetes Services are designed to cover most common uses for web applications.
> - However, as soon as you start working with application protocols that use persistent TCP connections, such as databases, gRPC, or
>   WebSockets, they fall apart.
> - Kubernetes doesn't offer any built-in mechanism to load balance long-lived TCP connections.
> - Instead, you should code your application so that it can retrieve and load balance upstreams client-side.